# Formula to Pull Unique Values from Another List Returns Zero and Blank in first two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Attempting to pull unique values from another list and am getting a zero in the first cell and a blank in the second. I am also getting a bunch of #N/A's which I can correct with an IF statement. But not sure about the other two issues... The list I am pulling from includes blanks but no zeros. Is there a way to correct this in the formula?

Cell B3: =LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,ATT!$B$2:$B$201)=0),ATT!$B$2:$B$201)

[image: ScreenshotShowingZeroAndBlankErrors]

[Screenshot of ATT Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cHLB.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Sorry.. I should have included that. I'm on Office365.. Specifically: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2201 Build 16.0.14827.20028) 64-bit

Comment: OK. If you add some details on the "other list" (sheet ATT, presumably), like a screenshot or something, we can change your formula to something much simpler. I think you're using something taken from a webpage or answer written for a much older version of Excel.

Comment: Oh awesome. I will add a snip of the ATT sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to put the unique names from column B of the "other sheet" into a list starting in cell B3 of the current sheet.

You can use `UNIQUE` to get a unique list. Note that if the list includes blank cells, they will return a 0 in the result. So, you can `FILTER` for non-blank cells first, then return the `UNIQUE` items from that filtered list.

[image]

Formula in cell F1:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($A$1:$A$12,$A$1:$A$12<>""))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so very much!!